# How to get element Id from dynamically generated form elements with jquery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic-forms

To try the concept, I'm doing a very simple test.

I got a form with some text input showing up from the start.
When I click on a field, I want to capture its Id, and add a value to the input text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').focus(function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#"+currentId).val('blah');
    });
});
```

This works great with the initial fields, but it stops working with the fields added using ajax calls.

The trick is, users are able to click on any field and I don't know which until they click.
My Ids looks like this:

```
experience0-CompanyName //(original one)
experience[n]-CompanyName
```

(the [n] part is also used to order the fields in the form as elements are grouped by experience, education skills etc...

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').live("focus", function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#"+currentId).val('blah');
    });
});
```

`.focus` only binds to elements that exist at the time it's called. `.live()` binds a function to an event for all existing elements, and any that are added to the DOM later.

Comment: As explained in this document, live() doest not work with some events.
Changing to 'click' instead fixed it. (almost the same event)
I choose this answer as a solution because it was there first and I do need to get the currentId for later use.

Thanks everyone for your help. You've set me in the right track.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are no longer appropriate.  They rely on jQuery.live, which is now deprecated.  In jQuery 1.11, a call to jQuery.live produces an error.  The current preferred solution is to use jQuery.on .  The implementation of the jQuery.live code, above, would be as follows.  The second parameter, currently set to ":input", can be replaced by a selector that conforms to your needs.

```
$( "body" ).on('focus', ":input", function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+currentId).val('blah');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler (no need to get id and search by it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').live('focus', function() {
        $(this).val('blah');
    });
});
```

Comment: > Hi thanks for the answer, but I just tried it along with the variant below with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are using `$("<someid>").focus(<function>)`. This works on document already loaded and not on new tags added.

`Try using $("<someid>").live("focus", <function>);`

Also do have a look at jquery website. They got quite nice documentation with examples. For live check this out http://api.jquery.com/live/