# How to get reference to calling control in jquery.autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an MVC page that contains multiple text entries.  The controls on the page are all data driven.  What I've done, is tag each of the autocomplete inputs with class="ACBox".  They all have their own Ids. I have also added a custom attribute called *fname*, where *fname* is the field identifer.  *fname* could be "size", "color", "connectionpoints", etc. (could be lots of these)

What I would like to do, is use one autocomplete function to make an ajax call to my controller with the *fname* of the control passed back to my function to return the appropriate list of possibles.

However, I do not find a way to get a reference to the calling object for autocomplete to read in the *fname* attribute.  My current solution below, the pfield is Nothing when I examine in GetOptionsFromField.

Is there a way to set **pfield**?  Optionally, I could use this.id to set as pfield.

```
$(".ACBox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetOptionsFromField", "ControllerX")",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    pfield: $(this).attr("fname")
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
          },
        minlength: 5,
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, It looks like I needed to search better.  This was answered back in 2014, [with this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507846/jquery-get-calling-element-id)

I use

```
$(this.element).data("colname")
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: This is what worked for me:  var controlname = $(this.element).prop("id");